# Is it possible to automatically (implicitly) obtain a new Google Recaptcha token?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Assume that we have a page with the recaptcha and a user has already successfully passed it. App sends a request to a server and everything goes ok. Next, the user wants to perform a similar request (which require a new recaptcha token on the server side) on this very page. Basically, I don't want to force the user to pass the same recaptcha again on the same page. 
So I'd like to know if there is a way to implicitly obtain a new recaptcha token.

Answer (score 0):

```
grecaptcha.reset(id_of_captcha_div)
```

This resets the reCAPTCHA widget. The id passed is purely optional. So the user has to re-click the captcha to solve it. This should also generate a new `token` for you to send to the server.

Comment: Thanks, but it's what I actually want to avoid. Once a user has successfully passed the recaptcha I don't want to show recaptcha widget to him anymore.

Comment: I see. I thought you wanted to show another widget. Well, I'm afraid, I can't think of a solution for this. Maybe someone else has a solution for this.